# Three table join count in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a problem here; when I do a query  :

```
SELECT product.*,product_description.*,COUNT(product_image.*) 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product  
INNER JOIN product_description ON product.product_id = product_description.product_id 
INNER JOIN product_image ON product.product_id = product_image.product_id 
ORDER BY product.date_modified DESC
```

I want select 3 table n 1 count for table product_image ,but I got this error :

> Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '*) FROM product INNER JOIN product_description ON
>   product.product_id = product_' at line 1 Error No: 1064 SELECT
>   product.*,product_description.*,COUNT(product_image.*) FROM product
>   INNER JOIN product_description ON product.product_id =
>   product_description.product_id INNER JOIN product_image ON
>   product.product_id = product_image.product_id ORDER BY
>   product.date_modified DESC

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `COUNT` function like this. `COUNT(TableName.*)` while joining tables. You need to use any of it's column like this `COUNT(TableName.ColumnName)`.

For e.g. `COUNT(product_image.ID)`

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd2e3/48)

Answer (score 0):

Use derieved query to count

```
SELECT 
    product.*,
    product_description.*,
    pi.Count as T_Count
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product  
INNER JOIN product_description ON product.product_id = product_description.product_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id , count(*) as Count FROM product_image) as pi ON product.product_id = pi.product_id 
ORDER BY product.date_modified DESC
```

Comment: the result of count(*) cannot return null in any case, so there is no use in putting the ifnull

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
product.*,
product_description.*,
COUNT(1) 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product  
INNER JOIN product_description ON product.product_id = product_description.product_id 
INNER JOIN product_image ON product.product_id = product_image.product_id 
ORDER BY product.date_modified DESC
```